# Call OData controller and Web Api controller from same url prefix (api/Controller)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, odata, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a service in asp.net web api. I am using its inbuilt aspnet identity authentication which creates an AccountControloller which is an ApiController. Apart from AccountController, my all controllers are ODataController and i have also updated WebApiConfig's Register method to call odata routes like this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<Post>("Posts");

            config.MapODataServiceRoute("api", "api", builder.GetEdmModel());
        }
```

Now my problem is that i want to call both api and odatacontrollers from prefix api but it is working only for api controller (api/Account) not for odata controllers (api/Posts).. I know if i will changes odata prefix to odata then it will work fine means (odata/Posts).. but i want to call both from same prefix. I have searched about it but did not get anything useful. Please help regarding this.